# Javascript create a modified html

Tags: javascript, html, dom

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
 <html>
 <head><title>Test</title></head>

<body>
    <table id = "summary">
        <tr>
            <th style="text-align:center">ID</th>
            <th style="text-align:center">Source</th>
            <th style="text-align:center">Operation</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td style="text-align:center">1</td>
            <td style="text-align:center">EcpR</td>
            <td style="text-align:center"><a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "showDS(1)">detail</a></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td style="text-align:center">2</td>
            <td style="text-align:center">SrcWP</td>
            <td style="text-align:center"><a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "showDS(2)">detail</a></td>
        </tr>       
    </table>

    <table id = "ds1" style = "display:none">
        <tr>
            <th style="text-align:center">ID</th>
            <th style="text-align:center">Server</th>
            <th style="text-align:center">ConnCount</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td style="text-align:center">1</td>
            <td style="text-align:center">108.123.0.1</td>
            <td style="text-align:center">26</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td style="text-align:center">2</td>
            <td style="text-align:center">127.56.27.1</td>
            <td style="text-align:center">127</td>
        </tr>       
    </table>

    <table id = "ds2" style = "display:none">
        <tr>
            <th style="text-align:center">ID</th>
            <th style="text-align:center">Server</th>
            <th style="text-align:center">ConnCount</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td style="text-align:center">1</td>
            <td style="text-align:center">118.103.10.11</td>
            <td style="text-align:center">206</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td style="text-align:center">2</td>
            <td style="text-align:center">87.36.127.13</td>
            <td style="text-align:center">17</td>
        </tr>       
    </table>

    <script>
        function showDS(i) {
            var detailedPage = window.open();
            /*
                do something
            */
        }
    </script>
<body>
</html>
```

I want to use the Javascript to solve the following problem: when user click the first "detail" link, a new html page should be opened, and the content of the new html should be identical to the previous one except that the "summary" table becomes "display:none" and the "ds1" table becomes "display:block". I think I need to copy the document object of the old html, do anyone known how to copy the content of a html including the tags?

Comment: i would suggest not opening this in a new window. instead perhaps use a 'modal'/'lightbox' and load the content into there. have a look at something like lean modal http://leanmodal.finelysliced.com.au/

Comment: I would re-open the current URL and communicate with the opened `window` to add a class or something. `var newWindow = window.open(document.location.href); newWindow.document.documentElement.className = "new-window-mode";`.